# dynamic content in Wordpress using php, mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, dynamic

I wish to create a Wordpress website that pulls data from a database. For example: a database of cities, landmarks, events, etc. I understand that Wordpress uses an underlying database, but how do I create a separate database to store dynamic data that can be pulled useing normal sql queries? thank you.

Comment: That's quite a broad question. To create a database either install phpmyadmin on your server, or mysql and use `CREATE DATABASE name;` but you might not need a whole new database and just a table so `CREATE TABLE name;`. To interact with that database or table you need to use php to `SELECT, WHERE, CREATE, DELETE` etc the information you need.

Comment: You need to use those commands with php, creating fields and doing actions triggered by events.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that Wordpress uses an underlying database, but how do I
>   create a separate database to store dynamic data

You can create a new database in mysql using the `CREATE DATABASE` command. For example:

```
CREATE DATABASE newdbname;
```

You can also utilize the Wordpress API for storing and retrieving custom data. This is a huge topic, but a good tutorial can be found here:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-writemeta-boxes--wp-20336

Basically, you need to register a callback to the `add_meta_boxes` hook, by using the following Wordpress function:

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'addMyCustomField');
```

And then write your call back function like so:

```
function addMyCustomField(){

    add_meta_box('id', 'title', 'callback', 'post_type', 'context', 'priority', 'callback_args' );
}
```